# installing openscenegraph on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openscenegraph

I'm having some trouble installing openscenegraph. I am currently going through this tutorial but I'm not sure what this particular part of the instruction is saying:

> http://www.openscenegraph.org/index.php/documentation/platform-specifics/linux/101-linux-stereo-configuration

The link above is #3 on the installing instruction that is in this link:

> http://www.openscenegraph.org/index.php/documentation/getting-started

In short, I'm trying to set my XF86Config file to driver TwinView mode for passive stereo. First off, what am I doing here? And secondly how do install this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TwinView is NVidia's version of Windows' Extend Mode - it makes your software think you have one screen that is twice as wide instead of two regular width screens.  If you have an NVidia card, these options should be available.  If you don't, you need to find out what your card's equivalent parameters are.

Open Scene Graph will then split the screen in half horizontally (thus the HORIZONTAL_SPLIT mode), drawing one eye's perspective on each half.  For a passive projector setup, you would have one projector for each eye, and a different filter for each (CW and CCW filters for circularly polarized, or Red and Blue for anaglyphic polarization, etc.)